# Android Emulator Can't Use WebCam as Camera

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm using AVD to set up a device. End goal is to click on the camera app and it uses the laptop's webcam. I don't even care what device, target, etc. I have to use. I just want one that works, and I'm willing to start from scratch.

If I emulate the camera, it works. When I have the camera set to Webcam0 in the AVD setup, the red light next to the webcam turns on and this is the image I get:

[image]

[image]

EDIT: For whatever reason, it's working now. The only thing I've done since the last time I verified it wasn't working was open the Lenovo - Web Conferencing app and clicked to show my video image. Since then it has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall webcam drivers and check if that helps.

a. Click `start` and type `Device Manager` in the `Search bar` and hit `enter`.

b. In `Device Manager`, `locate the device`, and then `right-click` the device name.

c. Select `uninstall` and `restart` the computer.

d. Let `Windows` detect the device and install the `drivers` by itself.

e. If that does not help, install the latest drivers from the manufacturer’s website

Comment: This did not work. I am now running an "Integrated Camera" Driver Provider: SunplusIT, Driver Version: 3.4.7.36

Comment: I can't help you any further, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation and the problem was also not in the Android emulator. I forgot to check the camera on my host system. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60232825/11130103)